# Can I run Compiz Fusion on an Intel graphics card in Xubuntu?

Tags: linux, drivers, graphics-card, compiz, optimus

I have a new state of the art Dell laptop with Xubuntu 11.04 on it. It has a hybrid graphics card with Optimus. The net is full of explanations why it's not working in Linux.

I was trying so much to get my NVIDIA card to work, I tried `ironhide` and `acpi_call` and `nouveau` but it just didn't work. See my other question here: [Xubuntu 11.04 and Nvidia drivers on Dell XPS L502X](https://superuser.com/questions/341421/xubuntu-11-04-and-nvidia-drivers-on-dell-xps-l502x)

Eventually I am stuck with the Intel card. My question: **Is there a way I can run Compiz Fusion on the Intel card?**

If yes, how do I do it? Because now, Compiz won't work ...

Here is my lspci -vnnn | grep VGA

```
  00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core     Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0116] (rev 09) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
  01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: nVidia Corporation Device [10de:0df4] (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
```

Comment: Which intel card is it? The 3000 series?

Comment: I added the lspci info for the cards

Answer (score 1):

Give BumbleBee a shot. It looks like ironhide is a port of bumblebee, but not sure what all has changed. I was messing around with this a few months ago when I had a optimus hybrid card. I was able to use Compiz with the Intel adapter while using optirun64 for applications.

https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/Bumblebee

Did you install the nvidia_current prior to installing ironhide? I've made that mistake before and Ubuntu didn't play nice when I did end up installing Bumblebee. You may want to purge the nvidia installation and try again.

Comment: I tried uninstalling nvidia. didn't work. I will try uninstalling it again and then installing bumblebee (what's the different form ironhide?)